# Mysql find the unique records where the data of a column changed

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a table

| Clientid | NId | Status | LastUpdatedById | AuditCreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | New | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:18:54 |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | New | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:18:51 |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:18:40 |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | New | 4376987 | 2022-05-11 14:54:18 |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | New | 200161 | 2021-06-20 10:20:15 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 22:02:08 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 17:19:52 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | New | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 17:19:43 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 17:10:14 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:19:19 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | New | 123456 | 2021-05-18 10:20:17 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | New | 123456 | 2021-03-04 14:20:58 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:29:03 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:19:03 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | New | 123456 | 2021-04-20 10:22:20 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | New | 54321 | 2021-03-25 20:58:52 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | New | 123456 | 2021-03-04 14:20:44 |

I am trying to find mysql query which find the row when the Status was changed from New to Paused and give me below table.

| ClientId | NId | Status | LastUpdatedById | AuditCreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26655777-9177-49b9-9ac0-0ac893fbde7a | 56565 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:18:40 |
| 35ad85c1-d986-48d1-a1cb-e8bbbe921611 | 2126335 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 17:19:52 |
| 5eac9c0c-057d-4926-bf56-394d36c51f04 | 2125219 | Paused | 3604561 | 2022-05-11 16:19:03 |

Comment: This can be done most easily using the `LAG()` window function if you're using MySQL 8.0. Are you?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal because you are using MySQL 5.7 and don't have the capability to use window functions, but this works to generate the result you wanted:

```
select t1.*
from mytable as t1
join mytable as t2
 on t2.auditcreateddate < t1.auditcreateddate
 and t2.status = 'New'
left outer join mytable as t3
 on t3.auditcreateddate < t1.auditcreateddate
 and t3.auditcreateddate > t2.auditcreateddate
where t1.status = 'Paused'
 and t3.status IS NULL;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/21BLqr66LJxupaGY6gEWB9/0